# Prepopulate controlled components

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

In my attempt to handle an update form, have written the code below. It is a controlled input component, with a corresponding state value. When a change happens on the input component the state value is updated. This means view will always reflect data changes and the other way around. My issue comes when trying to prepopulate the input component with data fetched from the database. My attempt was to define the initial state value in the constructor, to be equal to the passed props, but that did not work. When the component is first rendered it will not contain the passed spirit prop, since it has not yet been fetched. When the component is rendered the second time (because the data is ready) the constructor will not be called. How will I set the initial state when the data is ready and not before?

**SpiritsEditContainer**

```
export default createContainer(({params}) => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe("spirit", params.id);

    return {
        loading: !handle.ready(),
        spirit: Spirits.find(params.id).fetch()[0]
    }
}, SpiritsEditPage);
```

**SpiritsEditPage**

```
export default class SpiritsEditPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {name: this.props.spirit.name}
    }

    handleNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({name: event.target.value});
    }

    handleUpdate(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        const {name} = this.state;

        if (this.props.loading) {
            return <div>loading</div>
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>SpiritsEditPage</h1>

                    <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate.bind(this)}>
                        <Input type="text"
                               label="Name"
                               value={name}
                               onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>


                        <button>Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reword your question to explain where the problem occurs? e.g., how does a prepopulated form change the way your application functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor code may not work correctly:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {name: this.props.spirit.name}
    }
```

Instead check for props.spirit to be available.

```
this.state = { name: this.props.spirit && this.props.spirit.name }
```

Add a componentWillReceiveProps:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.spirit !== this.props.spirit) {
    this.setState({ name: nextProps.spirit.name });
  }
}
```

The rest of the code looks alright.